# Using shelve and sys module to make a updatable clipboard program

Tags: python, macos, terminal

Im trying to imitate this code from Al Sweigart's book but I'm not being able to run this through terminal even when im using the arguments mentioned in the script.Im not entirely clear with running  codes with input using sys module through the MacOS terminal so getting to know anything related to it would be really helpful!

```py
import shelve, pyperclip, sys

mcbshelf = shelve.open('mcb')

#Save clipboard content
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    if sys.argv[1] =='save':
        mcbshelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()
    elif sys.argv[1].lower() =='delete':
        if sys.argv[2] in mcbshelf:
            del mcbshelf[sys.argv[2]]
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
    if sys.argv[1].lower() == 'list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcbshelf.keys())))
    elif sys.argv[1] in mcbshelf:
        pyperclip.copy(mcbshelf[sys.argv[1]])
    elif sys.argv[1].lower() =='delete':
        print('Are you sure you want to delete every keyword?')
        if sys.argv[1].lower() =='yes':
            mcbshelf.clear()
mcbshelf.close()
```

Comment: You need to provide arguments from the command line to run this file such that it compares arguments and queries as provided in code

Comment: Near the beginning of the script, add a `print(sys.argv)` and see what arguments are actually being passed to it.

Comment: Note that `sys.argv` refers to arguments passed via the command line. Have you set up a `.command` file like he does in [Appendix B](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/appendixb/)?

Comment: @chemicalwill i have but im not able to run using the command file... It exits on its own in case of the regular clipboard program and its not able to find the directory or file in this program.

Comment: @HopelessNovice how are you running the program? In [Chapter 9](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter9/) he outlines how to run the program from the command line. It's not run by double-clicking the `.py`. If you can post the traceback, I'm sure I can help :)